# Can SafeHtmlBuilder excapse SafeHtml while still keeping SafeHtml the way it is(GWT)?

Tags: gwt

Here is my requirement. I have a textbox & user can type anything in the textbox and the system will convert it into html. However, it only converts `<b> or <i>` tag & ignore all other tags. The result of that text will be put into `<h1>` tag.

Ex, user typ in textbox: `<h1>text <i>test</i></h1>` it will out put:

## <h1>text *test*</h1>

So if user types `<h1>` in the text box then the system should be smart enough to know that it should escape that `<h1>` but then it has to put `<h1>` to the final string.

The code could be like this. I use SimpleHtmlSanitizer to sanitize string & only allows `<b> or <i>`

```
SafeHtml mySafeHtml=MySimpleHtmlSanitizer.sanitizeHtml("<h1>text <i>test</i></h1>");
```

so, if i print out mySafeHtml, then it will show like this:

<h1>text *test*</h1>

But Then how to make that String embraced inside  tag?

```
SafeHtmlBuilder builder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
builder.appendHtmlConstant("<h1>");
builder.appendEscaped(mySafeHtml); // err here cos SafeHtmlBuilder does not excapse SafeHtml?
builder.appendHtmlConstant("</h1>");
```

So how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on this would be something like this, why not check if your `mySafeHtml` starts with a `<h1>` and then conditionally append?

Example :

```
SafeHtmlBuilder builder = new SafeHtmlBuilder();

//check if your `mySafeHtml` starts and ends with <h1>

if(  (mySafeHtml.startsWith("<h1>") 
       || mySafeHtml.startsWith("<H1>"))
  && (mySafeHtml.endsWith("</h1>")
      || mySafeHtml.endsWith("</H1>"))
  )
{
    builder.appendEscaped(mySafeHtml); // err here cos SafeHtmlBuilder does not excapse 
}
else
{
   builder.appendHtmlConstant("<h1>");
   builder.appendEscaped(mySafeHtml); // err here cos SafeHtmlBuilder does not excapse  SafeHtml?
   builder.appendHtmlConstant("</h1>");
}
```

Comment: i found a better solution that is to replace all <h1> into  "&lt;h1&gt;" and then append<h1> & then sanitize but this time i need to change whitelist tag to include h1. Thax you anyway